# I am attempting to switch from mysql to mysqli and cannot see why there is a error on else statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have included the php code run on the server side that is failing with the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in
>   /home3/atljj/public_html/Osler/include/vo2_membersite.php on line 2849

No clue why it is stopping on the ELSE statement ???

Short story... I want to write a program to create and maintain a 1 record MYSQL control file.

I am writing the code in steps and so far have:

1. Written HTML code to via a form, submit to the server a request to create the table with the proper fields.
2. The server was then re-written to write the first record into the table via the INSERT statement.
3. All is well to this point... I have 1 record in the MySQL file and next I only need to update it.
4. The server was changed to test for a record already existing and if so bypass the INSERT code and run the UPDATE code instead... But I do not see where the problem is, other than I am attempting to use MYSQLi code now.

Is my table checking done wrong, I'm searching for record 1 and if not found use INSERT ELSE use the UPDATE...

```
function UpdateCase(&$formvars)
{
    $con = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->username,$this->pwd,$this->database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Failed to connect to MySQL");
        return false;
        }
    $c_match = $this->RandomIt();
    $c_username = "admin";

    $qry = "Select * from $this->case_c_table WHERE c_id = 1";
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($con,$qry));
    { /* first entry not found add to table*/
        $c_flag="M";
        $addit = 'INSERT INTO $this->case_c_table (
            c_match,
            c_flag,
            c_username,
            c_element,
            c_patname,
            c_patgndr,
            c_patage,
            c_patethncty,
            c_patdate,
            c_cc,
            c_td,
            c_lmpdate
            )
            values
            (
            "' . $c_match . '",
            "' . $c_flag . '",
            "' . $c_username . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_element']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_patname']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_patgndr']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_patage']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_patethncty']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_patdate']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_cc']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_td']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_lmpdate']) . '"
            )';      
        mysqli_query($con,$addit);
    }
    else
    {
        $qry="Update $this->case_c_table Set
        c_element=". $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_element']).",
        c_patname=". $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_patname']).",
        c_patgndr=". $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_patgndr']).",
        c_patage=" . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_patage']).",
        c_patethncty=". $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_patethncty']).",
        c_patdate=". $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_patdate']).",
        c_cc=". $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_cc']).",
        c_td=". $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_td']).",
        c_lmpdate=". $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['c_lmpdate'])."
        WHERE c_id=1";
        mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    }
}
```

Comment: you used `$this` in your example.  You also used unknown methods `RandomIt()`, `HandleDBError()`, and `SanitizeForSQL()` in your example.  Without the body of `this` class and referenced methods, it will be very difficult to help.

Comment: You should really be using prepared statements and parameter binding.

Comment: @Prix Post that as an answer